# how to set Height of uiview is differ from iphone to ipad using storyboard

Tags: swift3

i want to increase height for uiview only in ipad .below is my image

[Here is my storyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBgkV.png)

Thank you

Comment: ok, and what you tried for that

Comment: i am able to set height for ipad , getting same height for iphone&ipad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ipad height and width will be regular , so in storyboard click on height  constraint and then add select (+) on constant and select width&height to regular then you can enter what ever height you want on ipad , please check below image

[image: You can see this picture you will get exactly]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but where exactly the height constraint is?

Comment: you have to learn basics first, Selecting height you will see height line(with blue line side of uiview) click that line